# Scraping multiple pages with Python Beautifulsoup -- only returning data from last page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to loop through multiple pages to scrape data with Python and Beautifulsoup. My script works for one page, but when trying to iterate through multiple pages, it only returns the data from the last page scraped. I think there may be something wrong in the way I am looping or storing/appending the `player_data` list.

Here is what I have thus far -- any help is much appreciated.

```
#! python3
# downloadRecruits.py - Downloads espn college basketball recruiting database info

import requests, os, bs4, csv
import pandas as pd

# Starting url (class of 2007)
base_url = 'http://www.espn.com/college-sports/basketball/recruiting/databaseresults/_/class/2007/page/'

# Number of pages to scrape (Not inclusive, so number + 1)
pages = map(str, range(1,3))

# url for starting page
url = base_url + pages[0]

for n in pages:
    # Create url
    url = base_url + n

    # Parse data using BS
    print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()

    # Creating bs object
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

    table = soup.find('table')

    # Get the data
    data_rows = soup.findAll('tr')[1:]

    player_data = []
    for tr in data_rows:
        tdata = []
        for td in tr:
            tdata.append(td.getText())

            if td.div and td.div['class'][0] == 'school-logo':
                tdata.append(td.div.a['href'])

        player_data.append(tdata)

print(player_data)
```

Comment: add 4 spaces before `print(player_data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have your `player_data` list definition outside your loop, otherwise only the last iteration's results will be stored.

Comment: Thanks @Kostas Drk. Question -- does this apply for saving to CSV as well? When I replace print(player_data) with the following, it only saves the last page:      with open('bballRecruits.csv', 'w') as f_output:
                          csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
                          csv_output.writerows(player_data)

Comment: @NateRattner yes, whatever you do with that list, it's a matter of what is stored inside it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an indentation issue or a declaration issue, depending on the results you expect.

- If you need to print the result for each page:

You can solve this by adding 4 spaces before print(player_data).

If you let the print statement outside the for loop block, it will be executed only once, after the loop has ended. So the only values it can display are the last values of `player_data` leaking from the last iteration of the for loop.

- if you want to store all results in `player_data` and print it at the end :

you must declare `player_data` outside and before your for loop.

```
player_data = []
for n in pages:
    # [...]
```

Comment: The OP is asking about the returned data, not only what is printed.

Comment: Thanks @PRMoureu. I should have been more clear -- I did want to store all results in player_data and then print it at the end. So this was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Starting url (class of 2007)
base_url = 'http://www.espn.com/college-sports/basketball/recruiting/databaseresults/_/class/2007/page/'

# Number of pages to scrape (Not inclusive, so number + 1)
pages = list(map(str,range(1,3)))
# In Python 3, map returns an iterable object of type map, and not a subscriptible list, which would allow you to write map[i]. To force a list result, write
# url for starting page
url = base_url + pages[0]

for n in pages:
    # Create url
    url = base_url + n

    # Parse data using BS
    print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()

    # Creating bs object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

    table = soup.find('table')

    # Get the data
    data_rows = soup.findAll('tr')[1:]

    player_data = []
    for tr in data_rows:
        tdata = []
        for td in tr:
            tdata.append(td.getText())

            if td.div and td.div['class'][0] == 'school-logo':
                tdata.append(td.div.a['href'])

        player_data.append(tdata)

print(player_data)
```